# Why are there 6 automorphisms for this graph?

Tags: graph-theory, automorphism-group

```
    o 
    |
o---o---o---o
 \         /
  o       o
   \     / \
    o   o   \
   / \ /     o
  /   o
 o
```

(I apologise for the poor diagram unable to insert an image yet)
o represents a node and the dashed lines are arcs
My question is why are there 6 automorphisms for this graph? I can only identify 3 due to rotational symmetry.

Comment: there are also three reflections. Your diagram does not show those well, try drawing the main triangle as a circle

Comment: Oh right I see it now, thank you!

Comment: @WillJagy If you wanted to post that as an answer, I’d happily (+1)

Comment: @SantanaAfton I put a picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one has few enough points that we can draw a picture with the same geometric symmetries as the graph automorphisms. A rare luxury

[image]

Comment: As a note to the OP: the way Will Jagy has drawn the graph here should ring “dihedral group” bells for you (if you’re familiar with it).